# FragmentTransaction doesn't work

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I have a `FrameLayout` in my main xml layout and two classes that extend Fragment class. 
First, I have in `onCreate` method:

```
fragMng = getSupportFragmentManager();
mvp = new MyViewPager(fragMng);//ViewPager fragment
fragmentAbout = new About(0);//Simple fragment
fragTrans = fragMng.beginTransaction();
fragTrans.add(R.id.main_layout, mvp);
fragTrans.add(R.id.main_layout, fragmentAbout);
fragTrans.commit();
```

Then I need in `OnButtonClickListener`, the two methods `fragTrans.hide(mvp)` and `fragTrans.show(fragment.show(fragmentAbout))`. No result so far.

Comment: try replace method of FragmentTransaction instead of add

Comment: can you show your clicklistener code and logcat

Comment: I say OnButtonClickListener for example. I use OptionsItemSelected and switch operator. I have one button in menu "About". So, i need, when i click on this button, show fragmentAbout and hide mvp fragment, when i click another button, i need hide fragmentAbout and show mvp. @vo12 I'm trying to use replace method, but problem is still exists. May u give me some example code?